# How to group json by consecutive values only into a array

Tags: javascript, jquery

So what im trying to is group these values where section and row match and have consecutive order of startSeat and endSeat, i know I can use a reduce function.  I tried everything just cant figure it out

```
 const y = [{sec: "100", row: "12", startSeat: 1, endSeat: 2},
            {sec: "125", row: "10", startSeat: 1, endSeat: 2},
            {sec: "125", row: "10", startSeat: 3, endSeat: 4},
            {sec: "125", row: "10", startSeat: 9, endSeat: 10}];
```

so for example there are 3 items with section "125" but only 2 of them have consecutive seats,  1,2,3,4 the one with 9,10 has the same section but isnt consecutive, i only want the ones that are consecutive grouped into an array.  My new array should look like this

```
          [{sec: "125", row: "10", startSeat: 1, endSeat: 2},
           {sec: "125", row: "10", startSeat: 3, endSeat: 4}]
```

everything else should be ignored

```
   var result =y.reduce( (previousValue, currentValue, currentIndex, a) => {
    
   if (!currentIndex || (currentValue.startSeat - a[currentIndex - 1].endSeat === 
    1))previousValue.push([]);

   previousValue[previousValue.length - 1].push(currentValue);

   return previousValue;
   }, []);

   console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
const y = [{sec: "100", row: "12", startSeat: 1, endSeat: 2},
            {sec: "125", row: "10", startSeat: 1, endSeat: 2},
            {sec: "125", row: "10", startSeat: 3, endSeat: 4},
            {sec: "125", row: "10", startSeat: 5, endSeat: 6},
            {sec: "125", row: "10", startSeat: 9, endSeat: 10}];

let x = [];
y.forEach(function(element, index, arr) {
    let currentEl;
    for (var i=index+1; i < arr.length; i++) {
    currentEl = arr[i];
    if (element.sec == currentEl.sec && element.row == currentEl.row && Math.abs(currentEl.startSeat - element.endSeat) == 1) {
      if (!x.includes(element))
        x.push(element);
      if (!x.includes(currentEl))
        x.push(currentEl);
    }
  }
})

console.log(x);
```

This code iterates the `y` array, and for each current element (the `currentEl` variable) compares it to every other element that comes next and checks if it fits the "consecutive seats" criteria. For example, in the first `forEach` iteration the current element has an index of 0, so it gets compared to the elements with indexes 1, 2, 3 and 4. If it meets the criteria, the elements are pushed into a new array, only if they aren't already there. The next current element (with index 1) gets compared to the elements with indexes 2, 3 and 4. And so on until the whole array is processed.